# Lua seconds format questions

Tags: lua

I have this function:

```
  function SecondsFormat(X)
   if X <= 0 then return "" end
   local t ={}
   local ndays = string.format("%02.f",math.floor(X / 86400))
   if tonumber(ndays) > 0 then table.insert(t,ndays.."d ") end
   local nHours = string.format("%02.f",math.floor((X/3600) -(ndays*24)))
   if tonumber(nHours) > 0 then table.insert(t,nHours.."h ") end
   local nMins = string.format("%02.f",math.floor((X/60) - (ndays * 1440) - (nHours*60)))
   if tonumber(nMins) > 0 then table.insert(t,nMins.."m ") end
   local nSecs = string.format("%02.f", math.fmod(X, 60));
   if tonumber(nSecs) > 0 then table.insert(t,nSecs.."s") end
   return table.concat(t)
  end
```

I would like to add weeks and months to it but cant get my head around the month part to move on to the week part just because the days in a month aren't always the same so can anyone offer some help?

The second question is, is using a table to store the results the most efficient way of dealing with this given the function will be called every 3 seconds for up to 100 items (in a grid)?

**Edit:**

```
  function ADownload.ETA(Size,Done,Tranrate) --all in bytes
   if Size == nil then return "--" end
   if Done == nil then return "--" end
   if Tranrate == nil then return "--" end
   local RemS = (Size - Done) / Tranrate
   local RemS = tonumber(RemS)
   if RemS <= 0 or RemS == nil or RemS > 63072000 then return "--" end
   local date = os.date("%c",RemS)
   if date == nil then return "--" end
   local month, day, year, hour, minute, second = date:match("(%d+)/(%d+)/(%d+) (%d+): (%d+):(%d+)")
   month = month - 1
   day = day - 1
   year = year - 70
   if tonumber(year) > 0 then
   return string.format("%dy %dm %dd %dh %dm %ds", year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
   elseif tonumber(month) > 0 then
    return string.format("%dm %dd %dh %dm %ds",month, day, hour, minute, second)
   elseif tonumber(day) > 0 then
    return string.format("%dd %dh %dm %ds",day, hour, minute, second)  
   elseif tonumber(hour) > 0 then
    return string.format("%dh %dm %ds",hour, minute, second)   
   elseif tonumber(minute) > 0 then
    return string.format("%dm %ds",minute, second)  
   else
    return string.format("%ds",second)  
   end      
  end
```

I merged the function into the main function as I figured it would probably be quicker but I now have two questions:

1: I had to add

```
  if date == nil then return "--" end
```

because it errors occasionally with date:match trying to compare with "nil" however os.date mentions nothing in the literature about returning nil as its a string or a table so although the extra line of code fixes the issue I'm wondering why that behaviour occurs as I'm sure I caught all the non events in the previous returns?

2: Sometimes I see functions written like myfunction(...) and I'm sure that just does away with the arguments and if so is there a one line of code that could do away with the first 3 "if" statements?

Comment: I don't understand why you make `ndays` into a string there just to convert it back to a number afterwards. If I were you I would have done `ndays = math.floor(...)` and then `if ndays > 0 then table.insert( string.format("%02fd", ndays) )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not let Lua's `os` library do the hard work for you?

There is probably an easier (read: better) way to figure out the difference to `01/01/70`, but here is a quick idea of how you could use it:

```
function SecondsFormat(X)
    if X <= 0 then return "" end
    local date = os.date("%c", X) -- will give something like "01/03/70 03:40:00"
    local inPattern = "(%d+)/(%d+)/(%d+) (%d+):(%d+):(%d+)"
    local outPattern = "%dy %dm %dd %dh %dm %ds"
    local month, day, year, hour, minute, second = date:match(inPattern)
    month = month - 1
    day = day - 1
    year = year - 70
    return string.format(outPattern, year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
end
```

I think that this should also be a lot quicker than constructing the table and calling `string.format` multiple times - but you'd have to profile that.

**EDIT:** I ran a quick test with two functions that concatenate `"abc"`, `"def"` and `"ghi"` using both methods. Inserting those strings into a table an concatenating took 14 seconds (for several million runs of course) and using a single `string.format()` took 6 seconds. This does not take into account, that your code calls `string.format()` anyway (multiple times) - nor the difference between you figuring out the values by division and I by pattern matching. Pattern matching is certainly slower, but I doubt that it outweighs the gains from not having a table - and it's certainly convenient to be able to leverage `os.time()`. The fastest way would probably be figuring out the month and day manually and then using a single `string.format()`. But again - you'd have to profile that.

**EDIT2:** missingno has a good point with using the `"*t"` option with `os.date` to give you the values separately in the first place. Again, this depends on whether you want to have a table for convenience vs. a string for storage or whatever reasons. Combining `"*t"` and a single `string.format`:

```
function SecondsFormat(X)
    if X <= 0 then return "" end
    local date = os.date("*t", X) -- will give you a table
    local outPattern = "%dy %dm %dd %dh %dm %ds"
    date.month = date.month - 1
    date.day = date.day - 1
    date.year = date.year - 70
    return string.format(outPattern, date.year, date.month, date.day, date.hour, date.min, date.sec)
end
```

Comment: The os library can does even more work for you. If you pass the `'*t'` as a format parameter it returns a table with the information instead of a string so you don't need to do any pattern matching.

Comment: @missingno yeah, just saw that and edited it (giving you credit ;) ).

Comment: Thank you. On the return string.format how could I drop out the year/month/day if they were 0 but always leave 00h 00m 00s?

Comment: Using an inline if function: `function iif(cond,tru,fls) if cond then return tru else return fls end end` -- then you can do iif(date.year>0,date.year), iif(date.month>0,date.month), iif(date.day>0,date.day).

Comment: @Josh, that won't change the output pattern though.

Comment: @Col_Blimp in that case, your table approach seems alright (although I would stuff the time into a single field - to avoid calling `string.format` three times where one is enough). Otherwise, you could have 4 patterns (one with everything, one without the year, one without the year/month and one with only the time) - and have an `if ... elseif ... elseif ... else ...` chain to pick the correct pattern.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [os.date](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-os.date) function to get date values in a useable format. The `'*t'` formating parameter makes the returned date into a table instead of a string.

```
local t = os.date('*t')
print(t.year, t.month, t.day, t.hour, t.min, t.sec)
print(t.wday, t.yday)
```

os.data uses the current time by default, you can pass it an explicit time if you want (see the os.data docs for more info on this)

```
local t = os.date('*t', x)
```

As for table performance, I wouldn't worry about that. Not only is your function not called all that often, but table handling is much cheaper than other things you might be doing (calling os.date, lots of string formatting, etc)

Comment: @m.buettner: Ha and I also fixed another typo while you weren't looking!